# Moving PlayFramework 2.4.x View Templates into a specific Package

Tags: playframework-2.0, twirl

I'm on IntelliJ 2.4.x and I'm trying to move the Twirl view template into a specific package (not the default package `views.html`). The reason for this is I have a sub project and I'd like to avoid clashing view names by namespacing the two sets of views differently. Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid namespace clash just add standard namespace folders layout into views directory:

```
views +
      L com +
            L yourdomain + 
                         L yourTemplateFile.scala.html
```

Call it from a controller as:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def = Action {
      Ok( views.html.com.yourdomain.yourTemplateFile() )
  }
}
```

See [Twirl (Play template engine) project](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) for more details.

According to documentation extensions can be: html, js, xml, or txt.

The above works fine in Play 2.4 whether your use Play application layout or
SBT Maven layout as described in https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy

You can check SBT Maven layout test in a basic project I play with on github: 
[psmaster1](https://github.com/refond/psmaster1).
Here Twirl/Play templates are located in `src/main/twirl/views`